# Python: Error index out of range

Tags: python

Este es mi programa corto que estoy haciendo, la idea es verificar que en la lista no este registrado el producto que se ingresa y registrarlo, y en caso contrario mostrar que ya esta registrado dicho producto.

```
productos = [None]*3


pl = 0
while pl == 0:
    n = 1
    while (n == 1):
        produ=str(input("Ingrese el nombre del producto: Heladera, Termotanque o Lavarropa: "))
        i=0
        while (productos[i] != produ) or (i == 3):
            i = i + 1
        if productos[i] == produ:
            print("Ya esta registrado este producto")
        else:
            productos[i] = produ
            print("Se registró con exito")
            n = 0
    answer = input("Desea ingresar otro producto?('S'para si o 'N'para no):")
    if answer == 'N':
        pl = 1
```

Y me sale este error.

Soy bastante nuevo así que puede ser una tontería. Gracias de antemano

```
Se produjo una excepción: IndexError
list index out of range
  File "D:\Documents\Desktop\prueba21.py", line 10, in <module>
    while (productos[i] != produ) or (i == 3):
```

Comment: No sé que tratas de hacer con ese while pero sin duda da error por que `i` en algún punto vale 3 o más, lo que provoca el error, pues tu lista solo tiene 3 elementos (con índices del 0 al 2)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

el error es producido debido a que cuando usas un bucle while el valor de i excede el índice máximo de la lista.

Y precisamente por eso ocurre el IndexError, es como si intentaras acceder a un elemento que no existe.

**La mejor solución para iterar sin problemas en una lista es remplazar while por for.**

Ya que si prefieres usar while debes controlar en cada momento el tamaño de lista. for ya se encarga automáticamente de ello.

Espero haberle ayudado un saludo.

Comment: Yo agregaría para mejorar tu respuesta un ejemplo de como usar el bucle for y como se implementaría en el código del OP c:

Comment: Le comprendo pero la implementación de mi solución aportada en el código del amigo requiere detalles concretos respecto a que desea hacer. En determinadas ocasiones es mejor solución programarlo de nuevo y estructurarlo todo mejor. No quisiera hacerle perder su tiempo ni el mío. Un saludo.

Comment: Las repuestas con una buena explicación se agradecen. Sin embargo, siempre es mejor aportar código a la explicación. Por favor lee [answer]